# Remove Excel opening window (Excel 2016)

Tags: excel, office365, loading

To my knowledge, this question hasn't been asked before. 
If it has, then sorry for the redundance.

I am using Windows 10 and Excel 2016. What I want to do is :
When I open Excel, a green pop-up window is displayed for a few seconds, showing "Office 365", the Microsoft logo, and a loading menu.

Question > Do you think this menu can be removed, or replaced by some other image ?

Thanks a lot !
Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the menu can be removed: go to options excel -> accessibility (above advanced) -> startscreen...